# Solve $ f'=\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{f}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> How can we solve $ f'=\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{f}}$

My intuition says that we should integrate on both sides but doing it i don't think I get anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Rewrite the equation as

$$\frac{\sqrt f}{\sqrt{ c f - 2k}} df = dx. $$

Can you integrate it now?

Comment: do you mean $$f'(x)=\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}{f(x)}}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Comment: @Stefano Why should I split $f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}$ isn't $df $ and $dx$ meaningless outside integration or differentiation?

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc Yes, it is not a rigorous way to solve the equation. But it's what you ''do'' when you solve a differential equation via separation of variables. The rigorous proof (via Rolle's theorem) assumes you have already somehow solved the differential equation.

Comment: @Stefano would you mind showing how we can proceed from there?

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc In order to perform the integration we need to know more about $f$ (do you have any initial conditions?) and $c$ and $k$ (are they positive, for example?).

Comment: C is a arbitrary constant and $k $ is a positive nonzero constant

Comment: @Stefano we also know that $f''(x)=\frac{k}{f^2(x)}$

Comment: @TheNotoriousSc in this case I'm afraid we don't know enough about $f$ ($\sqrt f$) may not even make sense. I think The approach of LutzL is the best to follow.

Comment: @Stefano what would we need to know to approach it this way?

Answer (score 2):

Set $g=\sqrt{c-\frac{2k}f}$, then 
$$2gg'=\frac{2kf'}{f^2}=\frac{g(c-g^2)^2}{2k}$$
has no longer any square roots and can be separated and integrated.

Comment: How did you get $2gg'=-\frac{2kf'}{f^2}=-\frac{g(c-g^2)^2}{2k}$?

Comment: You are right, the minus signs cancel. Combine the derivative of $g^2=c-\frac{2k}f$ with $\frac1f=\frac{c-g^2}{2k}$.